# Changing Angular environment configuration to use specified build environment for Sentry error handling

Tags: angular, sentry

I have this basic configuration of Sentry in Angular application where currently, the environment of Sentry project  is set to either production or development based on the common value of environment.production boolean variable which is common for all environment configurations, like this:

**src/app/handlers/sentry-err-handler.ts**

```
Sentry.init({
  release: '***@1.0.0',
  environment: environment.production ? 'production' : 'development',
  dsn:
    'https://***',
  // TryCatch has to be configured to disable XMLHttpRequest wrapping, as we are going to handle
  // http module exceptions manually in Angular's ErrorHandler and we don't want it to capture the same error twice.
  // Please note that TryCatch configuration requires at least @sentry/browser v5.16.0.
  integrations: [
    new Sentry.Integrations.TryCatch({
      XMLHttpRequest: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

`src\environments\environment.stage.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  name: 'staging',
  auth0: {
    domain: '***',
    clientId: '*',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: 'https://***',
    requestedScopes: 'openid profile',
    database: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
  },
};
```

Right now I have more environment configurations than just production or development, like in this case where I have the stage environment. How can I change this logic in order to have the same environment in Sentry project as I have in my angular application?

Comment: `environment: environment.name`?